# return string pointer from function in C

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
TCHAR *sResult = (TCHAR *) calloc(16384+1, sizeof(TCHAR));
sResult = (TCHAR *) GetValueFromFile(sFilename,L"Dept",L"Names"); // #1
_tcscpy(sResult,(TCHAR *) GetValueFromFile(sFilename,L"Dept",L"Names"); // #2
```

Function:

```
TCHAR *GetValueFromFile(TCHAR *sFilename,TCHAR *sDept,TCHAR *sNames)
{
...
}
```

Which is correct to do? #1 or #2?

Thanks everyone.
Edit #1:

I'm using VS2008 in .cpp files, but really just C code.

I just need to open a file in GetValueFromFile and send the return string back. Should I be allocating memory in GVFF and freeing it in my program?

```
main()
{
TCHAR *sResult;
DWORD dwRetVal = GetValueFromFile(sFile,L"Dept",L"Name", &sResult);
...
free(sResult);sResult=NULL;
}
```

Like this?

```
DWORD GetValueFromFile(TCHAR *sFilename,TCHAR *sDept,TCHAR *sNames, TCHAR ** sValueData)
{
dwL = GetStringDataLength(…)
*sValueData = (TCHAR *) calloc(dwL+1, sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(sValueData,dwL,sDataFromFile);
}
```

Comment: How does the returned `TCHAR*` in `GetValueFromFile` get allocated?

Comment: WHy are you casting everything like mad?

Comment: @KerrekSB casting hides error messages :-)
Basically it means "I know what I'm doing" and when one turns out to be wrong...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Maybe he's using VS and actually compiling as C++ code.  JeffR, you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @AoeAoe: You do not have to cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  It is not an error at all, nor is it a warning on any compiler I have used.

Comment: @EdS.: More importantly, you certainly don't need to cast the return value of a function *to its own type* :-)

Comment: Is this Microsoft Visual C++? In that case, using `TCHAR*` for the function parameters and `L"..."` to call the function is not correct. They match only if UNICODE is defined. Either use `WCHAR*` in the function, or `_T("...")` for the literals.

Comment: @EdS. I know, I'm just pointing out that casting in C can be often dangerous and people often use it to make warnings go away. I misplaced my comment though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: if I don't cast w/TCHAR, I get compiler errors. I'm compiling as C++ code.

Comment: If you compile C with a C++ compiler what do you expect ? The real question is **why** are you compiling C with a C++ compiler (and mutilating the code to comply with  the weirdness of the compiler and/or the common subsyntax) ?

Comment: You could just shell out the extra zero dollars to download a proper C compiler if you want to program in C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off, this is unnecessary in case 1 and leads to a problem:

```
TCHAR *sResult = (TCHAR *) calloc(16384+1, sizeof(TCHAR));
```

I don't know where `16384+1` is coming from, so I'll assume that's "correct" for now, but you proceed to set the pointer to another value in the very next line.  That, my friend, is a memory leak.  Why are you allocating memory that you don't need?

Your question really boils down to the implementation of `GetValueFromFile`.  If that function returns a pointer (which it does) then it should certainly be a valid pointer and you are responsible for deallocating it (probably.  Again, depends on the implementation).

There is no need to create a copy unless you actually need a copy.  There is no "right" or "wrong" here from the information you have given us, we need to know the details of `GetValueFromFile`.

Per your edit:

That function does not return anything. At all.  It's signature says it returns a DWORD, not a `TCHAR*`.  It is obviously different than your first example as it initializes the pointer as an output argument (the 4th one), but that is not how you are calling it in your original example.

I am just further confused now, but if the function initializes the pointer then you need only declare (no memory allocation outside of the function) the pointer and pas in its address.

Given

```
DWORD GetValueFromFile(TCHAR *sFilename,TCHAR *sDept,TCHAR *sNames, TCHAR ** sValueData)
```

Then the proper way to pass your pointer in is:

```
TCHAR *result;
GetValueFromFile(filename, dept, names, &result);
```

The function initializes your `result` variable to point to a valid location.  **Do not forget that you are now responsible for deallocating it!**

Comment: The calloc() is only "unnecessary" (read: wrong, as in "memory leak") in case #1.  In case #2, the calloc() is necessary, since we need to allocate memory to copy into.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger: Yes, that's true.  Like I said though, it comes down to what `GetValueFromFile` is returning, how it is allocated, and if you need a copy.  We have no idea what the answer to any of those questions is.  I've updated my response though, thanks.

Comment: I fully agree with that part of your answer.

Comment: How do I get line breaks in these comment fields?

Comment: @JeffR: You don't, but you shouldn't post it in a comment anyway.  Just edit your post.

Comment: I changed the function to return a DWORD since I am returning the character array in a parameter in the function.

Although it would be nice to also return a TCHAR out of the function in case I wanted to put the function as a parameter to another function like _tcscpy.

Comment: I use UNICODE only, so it's a habit I use TCHAR instead of WCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

1 clearly is not correct. You start by allocating space with `calloc`, but then you overwrite the point to that space with the return from `GetValueFromFile`. Assuming no intervening code that saves that pointer somewhere else, this means you no longer have access to the memory you allocated, so you can no longer access or free it. In short, a big memory leak.

Depending on how `GetValueFromFile` allocates the memory to which it returns a pointer, #2 might be just as bad, but the code you posted doesn't tell us enough to know. If it returns something like a pointer to a statically allocated buffer, then chances are it's correct (for some definition of correct). If it's allocating space with something like `malloc` or `calloc`, and expecting the client code to release that when needed, then it has a problem similar to that in #1.

Note that the "for some definition of correct" basically translates to something like: "wrong the minute you have more than one thread, or any need for reentrancy". Given the current ubiquity of multicore and multiprocessor systems, that definition is pretty narrow now, and getting narrower all the time.

Comment: @JeffR: Yes, that's certainly one way you can do things. If you do that, you'd make the call like your #1, but eliminate the preceding call to `calloc`.